# Facebook comments plugin - How to hide comments behind iframe?

Tags: facebook, iframe, seo, comments

Since the  [Facebook Comments plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) is rendered as an iframe, there is no SEO benefit on the page from the contents of the comments. According to Facebook, I can grab the comments via the graph API (which I have already done) and "render them in the body of your page behind the comments box".

What exactly does rendering content behind an iframe mean? And won't that come under black-hat SEO (and hence get penalized by Google)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically it isn't black-hatting it, 'cause the information or text you'd be rendering would actually be legible on the page it self; you're merely making it more visible to SE's. This opposed to having none of the text being visible and just floating in the back to grab the SE's attention.

You can put the iFrame in a  and just append (or render) the comment content using the Graph API. Then you can hide it using CSS (visibility: none; or display: none;) or you can even use some JS to hide them, which would be easier depending on whether or not you're using a JS library like jQuery. This way your users can view the comments (once, hence the hiding of the Graph rendered content) and the SE's can also.

Hope this helps.